# php update--- T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING error

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

Please help me out here, im not sure what the actual error means but i am looking for any way to make this work! please!

```
    <?php 

//session_start();
include("config.php");
include("auth.php"); 

if($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] != 'true') {
//  header("location:member-index.php");
    }

//connects to database
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if (!$link) {
    die("Failed to connect to server: " . mysql_error());
    }

    //selects database
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
if (!$db) {
    die ("Unable to select database");
    }
```

this is where the error is

```
$qry = "UPDATE members set firstname="'.$firstname.'", lastname="'.$lastname.'", location="'.$location.'", email="'.$email.'", cell_number="'.$cell_number.'", home_number="'.$home_number.'", about="'.$about.'" where member_id="'.$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'].'" "


$result = @mysql_query($qry);


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$qry = "UPDATE members set firstname="'.$firstname.'", lastname="'.$lastname.'", location="'.$location.'", email="'.$email.'", cell_number="'.$cell_number.'", home_number="'.$home_number.'", about="'.$about.'" where member_id="'.$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'].'" "
```

to

```
$qry = "UPDATE members set firstname='".$firstname."', lastname='".$lastname."', location='".$location."', email='".$email."', cell_number='".$cell_number."', home_number='".$home_number."', about='".$about."' where member_id='".$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']."' ";
```

**Note : It is highly recommended to use Prepared statements instead of using mysql_* functions.**

Comment: Beat me to it ;)! Or mysqli

Comment: @Phorce: not _or_ `mysqli_*`, you'll have to at least use `mysqli_*` to use prepared statements. Passing this query to mysqli is just as dangerous as using a deprecated extension. Preferable use PDO, though, as it offers a wider variety of DB drivers and has a better api (IMO)

Comment: @Dr. Dan My bad! I'm tired, been a long night. Sorry, silly mistake

Comment: @Dr. Dan Thank you so much for the quick response! now I am getting Undefined Variable errors for everything (firstname, lastname, ....). If this werent for a programming class that I was only allowed to use the functions learned then I would have most likely chosen some other form of doing all this stuff

Comment: @SalZaydon Check from where you are setting values for $firstname, $lastname etc. You can use isset method to see if variable exists and only fire query when all variable exists.